# Android app to prevent more than one screen unlock per hour

Tags: android, lockscreen

In order to remove distraction, I'm looking for an Android app which would only allow my phone to be unlocked one time every hour (or some other controlled schedule).  (Possibly, you'd still be able to receive / make calls during the locked period.)

I.e. even if you know the PIN, you can only unlock it on a time schedule.

It's basically a time lock for the phone (similar to a bank safe time lock).

I would pay 20 USD for it.

Comment: Is it 1 or 2? (1) Even if you know the PIN code, the phone can only be unlocked once an hour. (2) Even without the PIN code, every hour you get one chance to unlock the phone, but if you have the PIN code you can unlock it any time.

Comment: Just curious: is it to remove unnecessary distractions? for instance to prevent procrastination. Context might make your question easier to understand.